# laravel livewire 3 I'm facing error in wire:navigate js file not loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

laravel 10 livewire 3 I'm facing error in wire:navigate js file not loading.
tried below code and followed documentation. still not solved

https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/navigate

I tried below code

***app.blade.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
        <title>{{ $title ?? 'Page Title' }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ $slot }}
    </body>
<script>
document.addEventListener('livewire:navigated', () => { 
  <script src="/vendor/fancybox/fancybox.js" ></script>
  <script src="/vendor/gsap/gsap.min.js" ></script> 
  <script src="/js/script.js" ></script>
})
</script>
</html>
```

***And Also Tried Below Code too***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>{{ $title ?? 'Page Title' }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ $slot }}
    </body>
    <script src="/vendor/fancybox/fancybox.js" data-navigate-track></script>
    <script src="/vendor/gsap/gsap.min.js" data-navigate-track></script> 
    <script src="/js/script.js" data-navigate-track></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your scripts after the *body* which is an unusual practice (if not downright a bad practice).

The conventional places where to puts scripts are the *head* and the *body* and Livewire can manage scripts placed in that positions.

You can use *data-navigate-track* when the scripts are set in the *head* and to force the page reload if needed.
*livewire:navigation* is not useful in this situation.

Comment: i moved scripts  inside body still not loading js

Comment: How do you know that libraries aren't loading? I did a test with the first one (fancybox) and I see in the browser's Network Monitor that it loads correctly . Isn't there a conflict with the interaction with Livewire instead? Does avoiding *wire:navigate* work?